# How do i use $scope.compdata throughout the controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

The variable $scope.compdata i am not able to access outside the controller. Thanks in advance.

```
  var compdata;
  $scope.fetchCompanies = function() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   Company.get({
      arg1 : 'list',
      arg2 : 14
    }, function(success) {
      $scope.compdata = success.data;
      deferred.resolve(success.data); //Edited here
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  $scope.fetchCompanies()
    .then(function(data) { // and this block
      $scope.compdata = data; //Added
      console.log("outside : ",  $scope.compdata) //success
    });

console.log("outside : ",  $scope.compdata); //undefined
```

Comment: This is because of async execution. The value will be undefined outside resolve of the promise

Comment: @bhavani you WILL NOT get access to the data `$scope.compdata` outside as you are setting it inside the async call i.e. ajax call.
What Exactly you want to do by accessing `$scope.compdata` outside ? kindly explain the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

try with below : declare the compdata variable as  -

```
$scope.compdata = '';
```

Comment: Thanks, Already tried but its not working.

Comment: okay... then try to assign the existing variable into your controller, and call as - 
var compdata ; is global variable  so 
compdata = $scope.compdata; 
console.log("outside : ",   compdata);

Comment: @Ganesh later console.log will get called immediately as soon as controller get instantiated , which will be again undefined as service promise is not resolved yet

Comment: yes again its undefined

Comment: I mean to say - 
$scope.fetchCompanies()
    .then(function(data) {  
      $scope.compdata = data;  
      compdata = $scope.compdata;
    });
console.log("outside : ",  $scope.compdata);